# Most surface area enclosed by fences

Tags: optimization

There two roads that interesect at an angle of 68 degrees, how should he put two fences(line segments) length L such that maximum area is between fences and road.
I'm guessing at a 90 degree angle between the fences?

Comment: No, split the 68° angle in half. Then place one fence on each side of the angle such that they form two isosceles triangles.

Comment: depends on how long the roads are.